# Disable Ripple effect on MUI Button and add custom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, css-animations

I wanted to remove the ripple effect on the button and implement my custom effect in MUI Button. I have removed ripple using *disableRipple*. I have tried to apply shadow when the user clicks on an element, but somehow it's not working.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { alpha } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default function DefaultProps() {
  return (
    <Button
      variant="outlined"
      // className='Mui-focusVisible'
      disableRipple
      sx={{
        "&:hover": {
          boxShadow: `0px 0px 0px 0px ${alpha("#000", 0.16)}`
        },
        "&.Mui-focusVisible": {
          boxShadow: `0px 0px 0px 50px ${alpha("#000", 0.16)}`
        },
        "&.Mui-active": {
          boxShadow: `0px 0px 0px 8px ${alpha("#000", 0.16)}`
        }
      }}
    >
      Change default props
    </Button>
  );
}
```

I have used Mui-focusVisible to apply shadow on click as mentioned here is [doc](https://mui.com/api/button/#demos)

> disableRipple bool    false
> If true, the ripple effect is disabled.
> ⚠️ Without a ripple there is no styling for :focus-visible by default. Be sure to highlight the element by applying separate styles with the .Mui-focusVisible class.

My main intention is to achieve a click effect same as Ant Design. Check the button here: https://ant.design/components/button/

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/defaultprops-material-demo-forked-rhggn?file=/demo.js

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### STEP 1: Disable default ripple effect

Disable ripple effect by adding [`disableRipple`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button-base/#props) like this:

```
<Button disableRipple>Text</Button>
```

#### STEP 2: Add custom pulse effect

The magic happens inside the `style.css` file. See the forked [CodeSandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/defaultprops-material-demo-forked-kyx05p?file=/public/index.html).

---

**EDIT**

Since you wanted the code to be inside `sx` I moved the code from the `style.css` file to the `App.js` file and placed it inside `sx`. See the  [StackBlitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wmc61x?file=src%2FApp.js).

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Button
      variant="outlined"
      disableRipple
      sx={{
        borderRadius: '5px',

        '&::after': {
          content: '""',
          display: 'block',
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          opacity: 0,
          transition: 'all 0.5s',
          boxShadow: '0 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)',
        },

        '&:active::after': {
          boxShadow: '0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)',
          position: 'absolute',
          borderRadius: '5px',
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          opacity: 1,
          transition: '0s',
        },
      }}
    >
      Change default props
    </Button>
  );
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

**style.css**

```
// Empty
```

Comment: This is good and correct but i wanted same in styleOverrides or inside Sx? can you d that?

Comment: I updated my answer. For some reason CodeSandbox wasn't working on the computer I currently use, that's why I used StackBlitz. Just copy-paste the code into your project.

Comment: I think it's also disabled tab behavior. Tab focus on button has no effect now.

Comment: how it can have the same effect as active.

Answer (score 5):

**It's much simpler than that...**
Just call **disableRipple={true}** and you're good to go.

Comment: well, you are right but my question was more than that. Thanks for answering.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31774449)